# Missing $ inserted error in overleaf

Tags: errors

[image]

I tried a lot but was not able to solve these 14 errors, but only once was the message sowing missing $inserted. I was not able to source it to the main document, so it just directed me to the main.tex.

Comment: In your code some in-line math expression is not closed by `$`. Please provide a small complete document (not its image) which reproduce your problem. Preparing it, you will probably find the error in the code yourself.

Comment: There must be one or more unclosed inline math expressions in one or more of the four external tex files that get `\input`ed by `main`. Not having access to these external tex files, I'm afraid it's not possible to give more specific advice at this point. To speed up the troubleshooting process, you could try compiling the document just one chapter at a time. (Hopefully, you don't have unclosed inline math expression in all four external tex files...)

Comment: give a link to Your project please (klick Share and atc.)